# How to include React-Admin In Another Redux Application

Tags: redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk, react-admin, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to embed [react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin) into another redux application.  The docs outline how to do this [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html).  However, the main app located [here](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-interface/blob/main/src/state/index.ts) uses `configureStore` rather than `createStore`.  Moreover, `createStore` in the `react-admin` docs passes in state i.e., the store appears to be dynamically initialized every render based on state variables.  What's the best way to integrate react-admin in this case?

Comment: Where does createStore uses local state in the react-admin docs? The example you linked doesn't seem to do that.